# How to render objects with only boundary and intersection lines

Tags: 3ds-max

I want to render something in 3ds max for geometry education purpose. I want it to be like in CAD softwares, with right outlines and intersection lines (but without lighting). Semi-transparent faces are also needed. Like the following style:

[image]

I want to know how to make this kind of thing.

Comment: Even in entry level CAD programs one draws and renders a lookalike (=without the ball cage and gaskets) in less than 10 minutes.(tested) It's a 2 part revolved solid + the balls. The model is not made of polygon faces there. It's spline based surfaces. 3DsMax should also have them. This type model can be rendered as wireframe, the hidden lines either removed or shown as greyed and it contains the wanted lines, no polygon edges. The rendered image can be exported as vector drawing for finer line type and color selections in Illustrator etc..

Comment: @user287001 different technology basis. Its like theres no reason why the 3D cad apps wouldnt have illustrators features in 2D mode but they dont. But yes there is a toon shader in max that does exactly the same thing just use lots of polys. Anyway note that your cad app probably wont render interpart intersection lines. Either you model it in or its not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No pinpoint answer is available, because we do not have a slightest idea what you have tried and what's the actual problem you have met. An easy response would be to give a close vote and do something else. But here's a guess (sorry, no 3dsMax, I use free and low cost 3D software, only simple and easy to use ones).

I guess you have combined ready to use 3D preset shapes and ended to something like this:

[image]

It has thousands of small polygons for smooth looking surface without a need to perform any actual smoothing. But there's no way to show it as the wanted lines except by mapping the wanted curves onto the surfaces (a hefty job). As a wireframe this would look hopeless and impenetrable mess.

The CAD style version of this is not a polygon mesh, it's made of spline based NURBS surfaces. 3dsMax also has a possibility to use them (cannot show how to proceed there). In CAD one draws a sketch for a start:

[image]

The circles are drawn to remember how big are the balls and where's the centerpoint.

Trimming off the unnecessary lines gives this profile (no proper clearances, this is only a lookalike):

[image]

The profile can be revolved (=lathed) around the forthcoming middle axis. In the next image only 39 degrees of the full turn is completed to show the idea:

[image]

As you see, the CAD program inserts also form curves. They come automatically to different types of edges and borders. In rendering options one can select which edge- and border types get the curve and which do not.

An array of balls is drawn, ready to be moved into the gap:

[image]

This is the result, rendered with algorithmic shading (sorry, no ray-tracing nor photorealistic materials in freeware CAD):

[image]

The parts could be colored with different colors for better clarity, but that's all in shaded rendering. Shading can be closed to see wireframe. Hidden lines can be shown like visible ones, they can be greyed or removed in options. Now hidden lines are greyed:

[image]

Quite a mess, I say. If hidden lines are fully removed the result is clearer (see NOTE1)

[image]

My opinion is that the best visualization with static-only  images is got by having different views, shading, different colors, transparency and only a few form lines. Here only the sharp edges have lines:

[image]

For even better clarity a version which shows the cross section can be useful:

[image]

The pieces are splitted with planar surfaces and sections are deleted. Tried also a new color.

===================

**NOTE1**: It looks quite rough and it is. The CAD program doesn't work too much for onscreen watching. For better lines and curves the image can be exported as vector (no perspective, only ortographic projection) and open in Illustrator. In the next image the colored version is exported as wireframe. The curves in Illustrator have inherited the colors of the shaded surfaces:

[image]

One can easily change line colors and weights.

**ADD due a comment**: There's a comment which says my version doesn't automatically show intersection lines. That's partially true (see NOTE2). In the left in the next image  there are 2 intersecting pieces which are separate, only moved to overlap. There's no intersection line:

[image]

In the middle the intersection is marked It's made by letting the red piece split the blue one. It's one of the possible ways to combine pieces.

In the right the pieces are moved apart. The blue piece contains 2 separate parts. They can be recombined if wanted and the line vanishes (tried), this program seems to remember they were a originally a single piece with no edge there.

**NOTE2:** There's a display option "show interferences" which is there for searching design errors. Pieces can overlap in art and software, but real solid materials do not allow it. Interferences are shown as bright red.

BTW the used program is DesignSpark Mechanical (a free version of SpaceClaim).

Comment: Thanks for such rich information. Seems DesignSpark Mechanical is great for my needs. I thought CADs were a little far from me.

Comment: Note: DSM is a very carefully decimated version of a high cost commercial product. Anything which can be seen as serious engineering to earn money meets an intentional limitation (=disabled function). You cannot for ex. print proper construction drawings, design sheet metal, build easily assemblies by setting placing constraints for separately imported parts nor use many most common engineering CAD file formats. Fortunately the core direct modelling capabilities  are there. Also free form surface tools (=good for artistic design) are disabled.

Comment: Maybe the image I chose was not so right. I'm going to draw much simpler ones like spacial planes, lines, dots, arrows or basic 3D shapes, in a relatively mathematical style with moving objects and cameras as animations. I think 3ds max or Blender are good at animations.

Comment: DSM doesn't have any support for animations.. You need something much more capable (and complex) for fluent work. 3dsMax and Blender are designed for such jobs.

Comment: Thanks. CAD graphics are great, but they don't do animations... Now I may have to return to the original idea and really learn some rendering...

Comment: In DSM some of the capabilities can be misused - for ex. numerical sketching with math formulas . you can use some parameter like it's time, or more likely the frame number.. But you must manually input the number and save the scene. Just it should be automatic.